# how does wireshark calculate the arrival time of ethernet frames

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to write a c application that logs ethernet frame arrival times to a database. I been doing some analysis with wireshark and can see that it displays the arrival time of the frame. I'm going to use `libcap` which analyses the pcap file and I gather wireshark also uses the pcap file. My question is how does wireshark calculate the arrival time of frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvTimestamps.html:

*While capturing, Wireshark gets the time stamps from the libpcap (WinPcap) library, which in turn gets them from the operating system kernel.*