# Does Wireshark's arrival time parameter mean the time at which the packet arrives at/leaves the server, or when it arrives at/leaves the host?

Tags: time, wireshark, packet

Arrival seems like a weird word to use for describing the time at which a packet leaves a host, but I don't think Wireshark would have the capability of determining the time the packet arrived at the server, unless that time was encapsulated in a packet the server sent back, or Wireshark made some estimate. So, I think Wireshark labels incoming and outgoing traffic times as arrival times, but I'd still like some assurances from the wider community.

Comment: Related/dupe: [how does wireshark calculate the arrival time of ethernet frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112056/)

Answer (score 1):

There are no timestamps stored in network packets. The time displayed in Wireshark is the OS timestamp when Wireshark actually encounters each packet, regardless of the time when the host sends/receives them.